# Android ListView last clicked item as first

Tags: android, listview

I'm wondering right now how to implement following functionality in best and most reusable way.

Whe then user clicks an item in the `ListView`, he goes to `DetailsActivity`, but when he comes back to `ListActivity` item that he clicked before is shown as first in the `list`.

I'm wondering should I implement some kind of sorting in `listview` or in `adapter`. Which way would be most reusable and generic eg. clicked item is excluded?

Comment: can you be more elobarative, do you want youe clicked item to be first or not?

Comment: Ok, I can help you on this part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert(T,%20int)) method from `ArrayAdapter`. When coming back from `DetailsActivity`, delete the clicked item from your adapter using the [remove](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove(T)) method, then insert the element at the first position. Of course, you also need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` when you're done.

To identify when you're coming back from `DetailsActivity`, you could launch it with `startActivityForResult` and modify the adapter in `onActivityResult`. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android).

Answer (score 1):

The most simplest thing I could suggest for it is

Remove the item from the list and the add the item to the list on calling on activity result.

Set the data to the adapter (may be using a public method in adapter class)

Call notify data set changed.

Answer (score 1):

Get the item position clicked from onItemClicklistener and delete the item at that position in arraylist or array and add it to 0th position. So while calling DetailsActivity instead of writing startActivity(Intenet) use startActivityForResult(Intent) and in OnActivityResult method do the above said operation and call notifydatasetchanged().